# nquad giving different result than tplquad for a triple integral

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I'm trying to do this triple integral in scipy:

[image: Integral]

```
from scipy.integrate import dblquad, tplquad, nquad

def inte(z, y, x): 
    return 2*z
```

with `tplquad` I get the right result:

```
volume = tplquad(inte, 0, 1, lambda x: x**3, lambda x: x, lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: 2*x)
volume[0] 
0.33333333333333337
```

While this is what happens when I use `nquad`:

```
def range_3():
    return [0, 1]

def range_2(x):
    return [x**3, x]

def range_1(x, y):
    return [0, 2*x]

volume, error = nquad(inte, [range_1, range_2, range_3])
volume
0.2
```

What is wrong with my `nquad` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stared at this problem for a while trying to figure it out, but I finally got it. When you pass functions as the integration limits for `tplquad`, the function arguments are ordered `x, y`, but for `nquad` it's `y, x`. This can be seen when you look at the documentation.

`tplquad`:

> **qfun** : ***function or float***
> The lower boundary surface in z. It must be a function that takes two floats in the order (x, y) and returns a float or a float indicating a constant boundary surface.

`nquad`:

> **ranges** : ***iterable object*** 
> ...If an element of ranges is a callable, then it will be called with all of the integration arguments available, as well as any parametric arguments. e.g., if `func = f(x0, x1, x2, t0, t1)`, then `ranges[0]` may be defined as either `(a, b)` or else as `(a, b) = range0(x1, x2, t0, t1)`.

```py
from scipy.integrate import tplquad, nquad

def integrand(z, y, x): 
    return 2*z

res_tplquad, _ = tplquad(integrand, 
                         0, 1, 
                         lambda x: x**3, lambda x: x, 
                         0, lambda x, y: 2*x)
print(res_tplquad)      # 0.33333333333333337

def range_3():
    return [0, 1]

def range_2(x):
    return [x**3, x]

def range_1(y, x):
    return [0, 2*x]

res_nquad, _ = nquad(integrand, [range_1, range_2, range_3])
print(res_nquad)        # 0.33333333333333337
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem clear to me, anyways, did you figure out what is the rationale behind deciding the order of the variables in the function declaration of the limits of the bounds with respect to the order of integration of the integral?

Comment: The `tplquad` documentation says the order is `x, y` where the integrand is `f(z, y, x)`. The `nquad` documentation says the order is `x1, x2` when the integrand is `x0, x1, x2` (if using `z, y, x`, that corresponds to `y, x`). As for why, I can only guess. My guess would be that scipy can inspect the function signature of the integrand to and then go from left to right for the integration and do the same for the integration limits (chopping off the left-most variable for the limit signature).